# Convert lat/lon to data in Georgia state plane

Tags: python, proj, state-plane

I am trying to convert some data in x,y,z (ECEF) to Georgia state plane. First I convert x,y,z to lat,lon,alt and then try to convert it into Georgia state plane. When I look at the data, the numbers don't seem right (looking at converted data that I have from others).

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform, CRS, Transformer
import pyproj as pyproj


x = 685204; y = -4557333; z = 2766371;
ecef = pyproj.Proj(proj='geocent', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')
lla  = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')
lon, lat, alt = pyproj.transform(ecef, lla, x, y, z, radians=False)

inProj  = CRS.from_epsg(4326)
outProj = CRS.from_epsg(2239)

proj  = Transformer.from_crs(inProj, outProj)
x2,y2 = proj.transform(lon,lat,radians=False)
```

Comment: Maybe you really want EPSG:2240 NAD/83 Georgia West (ftUS)?

Comment: "the numbers don't seem right". Can you elaborate a little on this, maybe show us some data and why you think it's not right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have several problems:

1. Your lat/lon position is in the Carolinas not Georgia so that would be the wrong state plane
2. you are passing lon,lat in and transform seems to expect lat,lon.

```
    x2,y2 = proj.transform(lon,lat,radians=False)
    print(lon,lat)
    -84.3859862 33.751748
    print(x2,y2)
    2508079.5486572017 -44604571.2905585
    x2,y2 = proj.transform(lat,lon, radians=False)
    print(x2,y2)
    -18455.16714831327 1371990.553063654
```

Which agrees with [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=2239&ops=1713&x=-84.3859861&y=33.7517481)'s answer